# Twitter Bootstrap loads also ".less" files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am having a weird issue over here. I am not using less, I didn't include less files and have nothing about less in my project but when I look at the Developer Tools of Chrome, it looks like some less files are being also loaded even there is no such directory as seems on screenshot.

Who is the responsible for it? :) I am on .NET MVC environment by the way.[image: screen shot of dev. tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Those were loading by the .map files which is also referenced in the bootstrap.css. I removed them and they are gone.

Comment: Yes, sourcemaps. I'm pretty sure there were at least two similar questions recently, but I can't find those quickly (deleted?). So it would be nice if you could improve your answer (imagine we have no idea what ".map file" is), so then we could redirect future duplicates here :)